# Google Hangouts can't initiate call (desktop)

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

I'm signed into Hangouts on my laptop (Windows 8) and have installed the Hangouts extension for Chrome. Chats, sms, video calls, and receiving phone calls all seem to work properly.

However, I am almost never able to initiate phone calls. I try calling a contact, or typing a new number in and clicking call. A new window pops up saying "Calling XXXXX", but after a second the page crashes and I get the chrome "Aw snap" page.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is your browser updated?

Comment: @Cornelius Ok thanks, that seemed to fix this specific problem. Overall I find the app way too buggy :/